# Can I render Shaders in the Skia Debugger?

Tags: flutter, skia

Currently, whenever I try to open a *Flutter screenshot* (`.skp` file) in the **Skia Debugger**, all shaders are just rendered as **black**, i.e. they are effectively not being rendered.

This is somewhat annoying because I can also not see what is drawn below or above because of this (I can at least hide the black shapes by disabling the draw call).

[image: Screen capture]

<sup>The black circle is actually a shader.</sup>

What is also weird to me is that the `paint` entry only has `"antiAlias": true`, even though, I supplied the `shader` property in Flutter. I suppose that it is not even imported, or maybe not captured.

The shader renders fine in Flutter Android *and* in Flutter Web and I captured this `.skp` file using the following command:

```
flutter screenshot --type=skia --observatory-uri=..
```